# Animate div height to fit new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to animate div height to fit new content with slide down animation.

html:

```
<div id="container">
    row 1<br>
    row 2<br>
    row 3<br>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var container = $('#container');
container.click(function() {
    container.hide();
    $(this).html(
        'row 1<br>row 2<br>row 3<br>row 4<br>row 5<br>row 6<br>'
    ).slideDown(500);
});
```

The problem is that animation start from top, not from current height.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgt4a7fr/3/

Comment: You have to grab the current height and animate it to the new height : https://jsfiddle.net/Lgt4a7fr/4/

Comment: @Anonymous0day Put it as an answer, waiting to upvote for you.

Comment: I'm waiting too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use for the jQuery `animate()`. Please see the below demo.

and also i was looking on your below part of the code. please think of appending the new items alone ?

```
  element.html(
            'row 1<br>row 2<br>row 3<br>row 4<br>row 5<br>row 6<br>'
        );
```

Kindly ignore if you have used this code just for demo purpose.

```js
var container = $('#container');
container.click(function(e) {
   var element = $(this);
   var height = element.height();
    element.hide();
    element.html(
        'row 1<br>row 2<br>row 3<br>row 4<br>row 5<br>row 6<br>'
    ); // please think of appending the new items alone?
    var height2 = element.height();
    element.css({height : height});
    element.show();
    element.animate( {height : height2} , 500);
});
```

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    row 1<br>
    row 2<br>
    row 3<br>
</div>
```